# Family of lines $\sin\alpha x +\sin\beta y +\sin\gamma =0$

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

Problem :

If $\sin(\alpha + \beta)\sin(\alpha -\beta) =\sin\gamma (2\sin\beta +\sin\gamma), 0 < \alpha , \beta ,\gamma <\pi$ then the family of lines $\sin\alpha x +\sin\beta y +\sin\gamma =0$ passes through

(a) $(-1,1)$

(b) $(1,1)$

(c) $(1,-1)$

(d) $(-1,-1)$

My approach :

$\sin(\alpha + \beta)\sin(\alpha -\beta) =\sin\gamma (2\sin\beta +\sin\gamma) $

$\Rightarrow \sin^2\alpha -\sin^2\beta = \sin\gamma (2\sin\beta +\sin\gamma) $

By using $\sin(A+B) \sin(A-B) = \sin^2A -\sin^2B$

But I am not getting any clue how to proceed further.. please guide thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On rearrangement, We have  $$\sin^2\alpha=\sin^2\beta+2\sin\beta\sin\gamma+\sin^2\gamma=(\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)^2$$

As $0<\alpha,\beta,\gamma<\pi,$ all the sine ratios are $>0$

$$\implies\sin\alpha=\sin\beta+\sin\gamma$$

Now use $\displaystyle\sin(-y)=-\sin y$

Comment: what to do further.. not getting anything to solve.. please suggest . thanks.

Comment: @user108258, Form my last step, $$\sin(-1\cdot\alpha)+\sin(1\cdot\beta)+\sin\gamma=0$$

Comment: thanks that was very nice. .great thank a lot ..

Comment: thanks @labbhattacharjee ..thanks a lot...

Comment: @sultan, My pleasure. Good Question, though